# Ruby gem Error "Google is not a module/class"

Tags: ruby, class, module, rubygems

When I first require 'roo' and then require 'google-search' I get an error

```
TypeError: Google is not a module
```

Again, I first require 'google-search' and then require 'roo' I get this error

```
TypeError: Google is not a class
```

See below for what actually happened on irb

```
{12:30}[1.9.3]~ ➭ irb
1.9.3-p0 :001 > require 'roo'
 => true
1.9.3-p0 :002 > require 'google-search'
TypeError: Google is not a module
        from /home/sagar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/google-search-1.0.3/lib/google-search/version.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/sagar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /home/sagar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /home/sagar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/google-search-1.0.3/lib/google-search.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/sagar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `require'
        from /home/sagar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `rescue in require'
        from /home/sagar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
        from (irb):2
        from /home/sagar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
1.9.3-p0 :003 > exit
{12:30}[1.9.3]~ ➭ irb
1.9.3-p0 :001 > require 'google-search'
 => true
1.9.3-p0 :002 > require 'roo'
TypeError: Google is not a class
        from /home/sagar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/roo-1.10.1/lib/roo/google.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/sagar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /home/sagar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /home/sagar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/roo-1.10.1/lib/roo.rb:74:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/sagar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `require'
        from /home/sagar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `rescue in require'
        from /home/sagar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
        from (irb):2
        from /home/sagar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fix for this would be to have Roo namespace.
I have modified the roo gem [github](https://github.com/sagarjunnarkar/roo). 
You can download roo-1.4.0.gem from github repository and install this version of roo

Comment: I don't see any of ur commit for this. Also you send a pull request to the gem maintainer